# how to install haxm v.7.6.5 on my pc?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, android-studio, intel-haxm

I want to install HAXM on my pc. then this error popped up "the system requirements are not supported" .

CPU vendor        *  Genuine Intel

Intel64 supported *  Yes

VMX Supported     *  Yes

VMX enabled       *  No

EPT Supported     *  Yes

NX supported      *  Yes

Hyper-V disabled  *  Yes

OS version        *  Windows 10.0.19045

OS architecture   * x86_64

Guest unoccupied  * yes. 0 guest(s)

then I tried to enabled VMX on BIOS, but when I try to install HAXM. this error popped up "the system requirements are not supported" .

CPU vendor        *  Genuine Intel

Intel64 supported *  Yes

VMX Supported     *  No

VMX enabled       *  No

EPT Supported     *  No

NX supported      *  Yes

Hyper-V disabled  *  No

OS version        *  Windows 10.0.19045

OS architecture   * x86_64

Guest unoccupied  * yes. 0 guest(s)

idk what's wrong with my pc, I also tried to turn on and turn of Hyper-V on control panel, but still intel HAXM cannot be installed

edited:
HAXM is needed for my school needs, this year's curriculum still requires HAXM during practice because it uses Android Studio. are there any alternatives to HAXM? of course it must be supported by Android Studio

Comment: You are aware that [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm) was discontinued, right?  What are you trying to achieve by using HAXM? I seem to remember that HAXM required Hyper-V to be disabled. Intel VMX (VT-x) is hardware virtualization.  Hyper-V is a hypervisor which requires hardware virtualization. Given that Android Emulator know can seamlessly use Hyper-V due to Hyper-V supporting Intel Virtual Machine Extensions, you should reevaluate, if HAXM is really required.

Comment: Talk to your school. They may need to clarify the system requirements, especially if they do not provide the systems you use for the education.